# Angular2 Error when binding input to property

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML

```
<announcements allowSelecting="true" (selectedItemChanged)="selectedItemChanged($event)"></announcements>

<form [style.visibility]="selectedItem!=undefined |styleVisibility">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.Message"></textarea>
    <input type="number" step="0" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.Ordering" />
</form>
```

Basically what this does is the first component announcements, presents a list, which the user can then select and item from that list and the selectedItemChanged event causes that item to be selected in the main component, which is what the 2 controls on the page are bound to.  I know that there is a lot more to do with forms, which I'm going to investigate after I get past this one problem.

The problem that I'm having is that the page is erroring out saying that selectedItem is undefined, which when the page first loads it is undefined.  So what is the "correct" way to get around this.

**Mark** I thought about using the ngIf and assume that will work, but what about if I wanted the form visible, in this case I don't, but in other I might.

**Gunter** I get a different error if I use the ?. syntax.  In that case I get this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 23 in [selectedItem?.Message=$event] in AnnouncementEditComponent@3:14 ("
@
<form [style.visibility]="selectedItem!=undefined |styleVisibility">
    <textarea [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="selectedItem?.Message"></textarea>
    <input type="number" step="0" [(ngModel)]="selec"): AnnouncementEditComponent@3:14
```

The way I originally had it the error was

```
EXCEPTION: Error in /app/announcements/announcementEdit.component.html:3:14
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Unable to get property 'Message' of undefined or null reference
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'Message' of undefined or null reference
   at _View_AnnouncementEditComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal (Function code:178:3)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChanges (eval code:12143:13)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges (eval code:12247:17)
   at AppView.prototype.detectViewChildrenChanges (eval code:12169:17)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChangesInternal (eval code:12154:13)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChanges (eval code:12143:13)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges (eval code:12247:17)
   at AppView.prototype.detectContentChildrenChanges (eval code:12161:17)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChangesInternal (eval code:12153:13)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChanges (eval code:12143:13)
```

Comment: AFAIR `undefined` is not supported in templates (not sure though). You can try `selectedItem?.Message` and `selectedItem?.Ordering` and check if the error goes away. Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Wrap your form with NgIf: `<form *ngIf="selectedItem" ...>`